# How to Handle Self-Signed Certificate Pop-up in Selenium using "nodejs?"

Tags: node.js, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

i take this article as instruction: [this is a java version](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-self-signed-certificate-pop-up-in-selenium-using-java/) i grasp the article's idea but can't implement using nodejs...

like:
Main thread:

```
When('getToURL', { timeout: 1120000 }, async function () {
    const openBrowserProcess = child_process.fork('./openBrowser.js');
    const pressEnterProcess = child_process.fork('./pressEnter.js');
  
    openBrowserProcess.send(driver);
    pressEnterProcess.send(driver);

  });
```

openBrowser.js:

```
process.on('message', async (driver) => {
  try {
    await driver.get('https://.........');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

pressEnter.js:

```
const robot = require('robotjs');

// Receive the driver instance from the main thread
process.on('message', async (driver) => {
  try {
    // Simulate waiting for the self-signed popup
    await sleep(5000);

    // Simulate pressing the "Enter" key using RobotJS
    robot.keyTap('enter');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

i have tried worker_threads / child_process but all faced some issues.... is there anyone could help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: i have fixed this! thx